# Display sendError message on xhtml page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

My error page is not displaying error message sent by senderror method. Error Page :

```
<h:head>
    <title>Error Page</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p>Error : #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}</p>
    <h:outputText value="#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}" />
</h:body>
```

I am sending error like this from a filter

```
((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(-1, "You do not have a active session to access this page.");
```

The correct page is rendered but I can only see Output as :

```
Error :
```

But the error message from javax.servlet.error.message is not printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggests that the `FacesServlet` isn't being invoked on the error page request while that's the one responsible for parsing all JSF tags and EL expressions in that XHTML file and producing HTML output. To confirm this, rightclick error page in browser and do *View Source*; you should not see any JSF/EL things in there, but pure JSF-generated HTML output.

You need to make sure that the `<error-page><location>` in `web.xml` matches the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as defined in `web.xml`. If you for example mapped it on an URL pattern of `/faces/*`, then the error page location must be like `/faces/error.xhtml`. Otherwise, change the `FacesServlet` mapping to `*.xhtml`, so that you never need to worry about virtual URLs.

That said, `-1` is **absolutely not** a valid [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) to start with. Something in 4xx range is more appropriate for this. E.g. `400` or perhaps `401` depending on how you're doing authentication.